# SCSS Text decoration on child element

Tags: css, sass

what's the right syntax of applying text decoration on nested  while hovering.

For example let's say we have the **HTML structure**:

```html
<div class="main-wrapper">
 <img src="/abcd.jpg" /> 
 <a href="http://www.google.com"> Click me! </a>
</div>
```

I want to apply **text-decoration: underline on a(link)** element while hovering **main-wrapper**

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

you want scss

```
    .main-wrapper{
      a {
        text-decoration: none;
      }

      &:hover {
        a {
          text-decoration: underline;
        }
      }
    }
```

which gives css mentioned below

```css
.main-wrapper:hover a {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.main-wrapper a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-wrapper">
  <img src="/abcd.jpg" />
  <a href="http://www.google.com"> Click me! </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
div:hover a {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```